# Ошибка Nginx'a, выдает 404

Tags: nginx

Делаю почтовый сервер, делаю по инструкции, но там используются старые версии (например php), но на этапе когда надо войти в http://<IP-адрес сервера>/postfixadmin/public/setup.php Мне выдается ошибка

```
nginx error!

The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.

Something has triggered missing webpage on your website. This is the default error page for nginx that is distributed with Rocky Linux. It is located /usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html

You should customize this error page for your own site or edit the error_page directive in the nginx configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.

For information on Rocky Linux, please visit the Rocky Linux website. The documentation for Rocky Linux is available on the Rocky Linux website."
```

В чем может проблема понять особо не могу, логи смотрел,  они ругаются только, что нет изображений, а других ошибок нет

Конфиг Nginx'a

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            set $root_path /usr/share/nginx/html;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME "$root_path$fastcgi_script_name";
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT "$root_path";
        }
    }
```

В чем может быть проблема?